# does the inside of if condition make changes to objects?

Tags: objective-c, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble understanding this piece of code:

```
    // assuming fm is NSFileManager object
    if ([fm moveItemAtPath: @"newfile" toPath: @"newfile2" error: NULL] == NO){
                NSLog(@"File rename Failed");
                }
```

the moveItemAtPath method sends message in if condition. 
does it actually rename newfile to newfile2 or is this just some test, to se if renaming file is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression inside `if` will move the file if it can. The return value lets you find out after the fact if an actual change occurred. (For instance, if you are passing a path that does not exist you will receive `NO`.)